# Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

Using a FutureBuilder, I get the following errors.

> Error: The argument type 'AsyncSnapshot' can't be assigned
> to the parameter type 'Position'.
> Pointing to line: return Map(snapshot);
>
> Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null.
> Pointing to line: builder: ( context, snapshot)

home.dart

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: FittedBox(
            child: Text('something something'),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
           //irrelevant code for buttons etc

        ],
   body: FutureBuilder <Position> (
        future: _geolocatorService.getInitialLocation(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {

              if (snapshot.hasData) {   //<- can confirm snapshot has data and can display it 
                                        //  printed in terminal ex.: lat value, long, 
                                        // null,null
                                             
              print(snapshot);
              return Map(snapshot);    //<-having trouble passing snapshot data as Position to 
                                       //  this map
               }
              }
         ),
);
```

geolocator_service.dart file: (imported to home.dart):

```
class GeolocatorService {

  Stream<Position> getCurrentLocation()  {
        return Geolocator.getPositionStream(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,distanceFilter: 10);
  }

    Future <Position> getInitialLocation() async {
            return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
  }`
```

Map.dart file (necessary plugins are imported):

```
class Map extends StatefulWidget {

  final Position initialPosition;

  Map(this.initialPosition);  // <- initialPosition doesnt like the snapshot value

  @override
  _MapState createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {

  final GeolocatorService geolocatorService = GeolocatorService();

  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng( widget.initialPosition.latitude, widget.initialPosition.longitude),
              zoom: 19),
              mapType: MapType.normal,
        ) ,
      )
      );

  }
}
```

**EDIT:** if I remove the if-conditions:

```
body: FutureBuilder <Position> (
            future: _geolocatorService.getInitialLocation(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              
              return Map(snapshot.data!);

                   }
```

It runs, **BUT** I get a brief red screen error:

> The following _CastError was thrown building FutureBuilder>>>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#55f91):
> Null check operator used on a null value

Then runs as usual. Maybe because it was waiting for data to come in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return a widget in else condition. then `builder` required a widget and when you added if condition it won't return any widget until the if condition get true value and returns a widget.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: FittedBox(child: Text('something something')),
    body: FutureBuilder <Position> (
      future: _geolocatorService.getInitialLocation(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {  
          //<- can confirm snapshot has data and can display it 
          //  printed in terminal ex.: lat value, long, 
          // null,null
          print(snapshot);
          return Map(snapshot);
        }else{

        /// Display a loader untill data is not fetched from server
        return CirclularProgressIndicator(); 
      }
   }
 ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it!

Answer (score 1):

Another tip if the answer above doesn't work. Just make sure you're returning something in all your if and else statements.
E.g. return Column().

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32904408)